# Integer types in C

Tags: c, int, c99, c11

Suppose I wish to write a C program (C99 or C2011) that I want to be completely portable and not tied to a particular architecture.

It seems that I would then want to make a clean break from the old integer types (`int`, `long`, `short`) and friends and use *only* `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `int32_t` and so on (perhaps using the the `least` and `fast` versions as well).

What then is the return type of `main`?  Or *must* we strick with `int`?  Is it required by the standard to be `int`?

GCC-4.2 allows me to write

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int32_t main() {
    printf("Hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

but I cannot use `uint32_t` or even `int8_t` because then I get

```
hello.c:3: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
```

This is because of a typedef, no doubt.  It seems this is one case where we are stuck with having to use the unspecified size types, since it's not truly portable unless we leave the return type up to the target architecture.  Is this interpretation correct?  It seems odd to have "just one" plain old `int` in the code base but I am happy to be pragmatic.

Comment: What portability issue do you perceive from using `int` as the return type from `main()`?

Comment: int is portable in the sense it will compile on any machine. Now you will get problems if you say try to return 12344567891233445567 but let's be honest when was the last time you did that? All the numbers you return should be reasonably small. e.g. the error code.

Comment: I realize that using `int` makes the program portable in just this case, whereas everywhere else it seems portability demands the use of the fixed size types.  Maybe it is just a necessary asymmetry.

Comment: For portability you must assume a level of compliance with the standards. If an implementation is non-compliant, all bets are off. Otherwise, you can use `int`s in many situations without worries about portability. For example, you can assume a range of +/- 32767.

Comment: Does your code's portability REALLY depend on the size of `int` that much anyway? For a large amount of usage, [such as short loops], the size of the integer is completely irrelevant. You are just putting more complexity into the code and potentially making the code slower by forcing the compiler to use types that isn't necessarily the ideal one. That may indeed help in a few places, but in most places, it's probably not that important.

Comment: Agreed that differences would show up only in edge cases, but I'm more interested in the fact that languages like Java tell you the exact sizes of numeric types for the express purpose of being portable.  It appears that newer versions of C are trying to do that as well with `stdint.h` but the idea cannot be carried over to the return type of main, which by its nature is probably machine dependent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Suppose I wish to write a C program (C99 or C2011) that **I want to be
>   completely portable** and not tied to a particular architecture.
>
> It seems that **I would then want to make a clean break from the old
>   integer types (int, long, short) and friends and use only int8_t,
>   uint8_t, int32_t and so on** (perhaps using the the least and fast
>   versions as well).

These two affirmations, in bold, are contradictory. That's because whether `uint32_t`, `uint8_t` and al are available or not is actually implementation-defined (C11, 7.20.1.1/3: *Exact-width integer types*).

If you want your program to be truly portable, you must use the built-in types (`int`, `long`, etc.) and stick to the minimum ranges defined in the C standard (i.e.: C11, 5.2.4.2.1: *Sizes of integer types*),

Per example, the standard says that both `short` and `int` should range from *at least* -32767 to *at least* 32767. So if you want to store a bigger or lesser value, say 42000, you'd use a `long` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The return type of `main` is required by the Standard to be `int` in C89, C99 and in C11.

Now the exact-width integer types are alias to integer types. So if you use the right alias for `int` it will still be valid.

For example:

```
int32_t main(void)
```

if `int32_t` is a typedef to `int`.

Comment: I figured as much, but was unable to find a free version of the C99 or C11 standards.  The latest freebie I could find was [this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) dated 2005.

Comment: You can find the lastest draft for C99 here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf and the lastest draft for C11 here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf